# Searching for substrings in a text file - java

Tags: java, file, search, substring

I am working on a tedious assignment, but I am stuck on a part that I thought would be rather simple..I need to search for 'names' in a text file. The names are indicated with a hyphen before, so for example

"Hello this is an example, if we were to use -john, then john would be the name I would be looking for"

I need to get 'John' in this case and store it into a list.

I know how read lines, with the fileReader and readLine functions of java..but I do not know how to look for characters in a text file, like searing for the hyphen and then creating a short substring after the hyphen and the next space to indicate the name. Can someone help me with pseudo code or a function that I am not aware of that can make this easier? I apologize if I sound awfully confusing!

Comment: Generally, hyphens can be used in a more practical sense, such as hyphenated words. Is this the case inside your text file?

Comment: Yes, I was using hyphen as an example. The case in my assignment uses backslash, like "hello \john, how are you". In this case I were to search for the backslash to indicate that a name follows after, and store the name, 'john' into a list.

Comment: You have multiple options after splitting lines on whitespace, such as `.contains()` or the use of `regex`(which is probably overkill for this).

Comment: Yeah I think regex is actually the right way to go for this assignment, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String line;
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToSearch));
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  arr[] = line.split(" ");
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].contains("\\"))
      list.add(arr[i].substring(arr[i].indexOf("\\") + 1);
  }
return list;
```

Comment: Please be careful with the lexic: Backslash character must be escapped.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for and the direction I was originally working towards, but I keep getting this one error, even with this code. Whenever I use the contains method,

'if(arr[i].contains("\"))'

it gives me an error that suggests I insert more quotes and then proceeds to make the code even worse..do you know what is going on there?

Comment: The error is
'String literal is not properly closed by a double quote'
suggested fix
'insert missing quotes' which makes it worse

Comment: as stated by @LittleSanti, remember to escape the backslash character. see edit

Comment: Is there something else I can use instead of 'indexOf'? I get the error message that the method is undefined even though I thought indexOf was an already implemented java function

Comment: since you know the backslash will precede the name, you could just put `list.add(arr[i].substring(1));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86643/discussion-between-nlee-and-user201535).

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex on the lines to look for a name within the String. A regex expression is something which is used to find and match certain characteristics within a given String.

So for your example, with a backslash, you would use the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-.");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\\Tom");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The "-." represents the pattern of any character(s) directly after a '\'. Note that because '\' is an escape character, it must be preceded by another '\'.

If you wish to make it only accept characters in the alphabet, you can use "-/^[A-z]+$/", which basically only looks for hyphens directly followed by characters in the alphabet.

I recommend you to read up on regex, and the different expressions that it has to offer.

[Pattern class,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
[Matcher class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

In addition, a good resource for learning about Regex would be [Regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), which allows you to look up regex references, and try out various expressions online.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Pattern and Matcher to solve the problem.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Hello this is an example, if we were to use -john, then john would be the name I would be looking for.  Another example would be -ebenezer which should return ebenezer";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

        while (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
-john
-ebenezer
```

Note that this will not catch any matches that wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could solve this. Probably the easiest if you understand regular expressions is to use Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("names.txt")); //use path to your file
final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s(-\\w+)\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String name = matcher.group(1);
        //optionally, remove the -
        name = name.substring(1);
        names.add(name);
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")))) {
    int c;
    StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean inName = false;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        if (inName) nameBuilder.append((char)c);
        if ((char) c == '-') inName = true;
        else if (inName && (char) c == ' ') {
            inName = false;
            System.out.println(nameBuilder);
            nameBuilder.delete(0, nameBuilder.length());
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```